# Schedule cron job laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5

I will like to know how to schedule a cron job to run everyday at 00:01.

I have created `JOB` in `App/Jobs` folder

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Models\Result;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use DB;

set_time_limit(0);

class UpdateActive extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
    public static function ActiveUpdate()
    {
        Result::update(['draw_id' => 1, 
                        'isactive' => 0
                       ]);
     }

   public static function downGrade()
   {
   try {
        UserRole::update(['permission' => 1,
                         'isactive' => 2    
        ]);
   } catch (QueryException $e ) {
     //handle error
   }
   }

   public static function handle() 
   {
     self::ActiveUpdate();
     self::downGrade();
   }
 }
```

in App/Console/Kernel.php I have added this link to the `schedule` method

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        /*$schedule->command('inspire')
                 ->hourly(); */
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $check_draw = \App\Jobs\UpdateActive::ActiveUpdate();

        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

**Please note I have used everyMinute for test purpose**

In `crontab -e` I then added

`* * * * * php /home/vagrant/Code/projects/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

but the schedule doesn't seem to run i think because when i check my `results` table the `isactive` field hasn't changed.

I am wondering where I am going wrong please. If anyone has done this in L5. What am I missing?

Comment: What does laravel.log say?

Comment: It seem to be working now. The query was throwing an exception. Thanks all

Comment: There is no point having this as a Job implementing self handling. You have made them all static functions...

Comment: @fungku i should only implement "self handling" if i am running the **whole class** as a job?

Comment: Well, ideally, you should only use the `Job` class if what you are doing is a single task, and the task is executed in the `handle` method (which shouldn't be static).

Comment: @fungku i dont mind editing my class to work the way it is intended to, but i need to break it into 2 functions(as shown above). How can I do this please.

Comment: @fungku using the example above in the question can you edit your answer to show how this can be done, the way it was intended. thanks

Comment: @Baako I updated the **Aside** section of my answer to include one way you could do it.

Comment: ...if you really want to do this with `Job`s, that is.

Comment: @fungku yes its needs to be a job run by cron because i do not want this to be accessible via broswer or anything else apart from cron

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I will like to know how to schedule a cron job to run everyday at 00:01.

So you want it to run daily at 00:01?

## Answer:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $check_draw = \App\Jobs\UpdateActive::ActiveUpdate();
    })->dailyAt("00:01");
}
```

### *Aside: (edited in response to your comments)*

This is how I would do it:

The command:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class UpdateActiveCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'update-active';

    protected $description = 'Update something?';

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->comment("Update active...");
            $this->updateActive();

            $this->comment("Downgrade...");
            $this->downGrade();

            $this->info("Done!");
        } catch (QueryException $e ) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

     private function updateActive()
     {
        Result::update([
            'draw_id'  => 1, 
            'isactive' => 0,
        ]);
     }

     private function downGrade()
     {
        UserRole::update([
            'permission' => 1,
            'isactive'   => 2,
        ]);
     }
}
```

The scheduler:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\UpdateActiveCommand::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('update-active')
                 ->dailyAt('00:01')
                 ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/update-active.log'))
                 ->emailOutputTo('baako@baako.com');
    }
}
```

If you did it this way you could also run it from the command line with `php artisan update-active` and see the output.

Comment: I dont quiet understand `DispatchesJobs` but from what `I` seem to get from this is that you are running dispatching a job for every function in the `UpdateActive` class which is not what I want to do.

Comment: @Baako It only executes the `handle` method. However, It seems like maybe you don't want your `UpdateActive` class to be a [Job](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-class-structure), and no point in implementing the `SelfHandling` interface either.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. I have updated my question to how i am active using the `handle` function and how i am calling it in the `schedule` function.

Comment: **P.S** the cron job doesn't seem to run daily, it only ran once and that was it. Do I need to actually set the time on crontab instead of relation on laravel to handle it for me?

Comment: @Baako crontab should be `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1` where `path/to/artisan` is the path to your project artisan file

Comment: `path/to/artisan` is the path to your project root which i have included in the above. According laravel docs [Link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands) which shows the same example you have included and i have used, it says that the schedule will run "every minute". I don't understand why it ran the first time i added it in `crontab -e` but didn't run again at `00:01`

Comment: The `scheduler` runs every minute (`schedule:run`) and checks if a task you have is due to run. So, your tasks will only run when you schedule them to.

Comment: @funku thanks for the update, i really appropriate it.  Please correct me if i am wrong but in the `Kernel ` class it seems to me that you are only scheduling the job for the `downgrade `. With a real life usage of what i am trying to do please [click here on this kopi link](http://kopy.io/r0wzW)

Comment: @Baako you don't need to split it, but I don't see the point of the static methods. Check it out as a [console command](http://kopy.io/CZE8U#0r31BtuxmSLyDb).

Comment: Oh I see so i can do this without having to set it has a job and use command instead.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a Job or Command it could be just your own class. However, since it is scheduled as a cron job I think it's nice to make it a console command.

Comment: if you notice the `creawDraw` method accepted a datetime argument `public function createDraw(\DateTime $date = null)` but in your example you seem to changed it. The reason why i added that argument was because if i wanted to run a `draw` for a specific date, i can then do it like that. is that something you will advise doing via `command` or should i create a duplicate of this in the `controller` to handle this?

Comment: words can't express how happy i am with your help. Thank you again

Comment: as a console command you can pass it in with an argument [kopy.io](http://kopy.io/Ouvw6#PH2Vba0Xj4RaKk) then you would do like, `php artisan test {date}` e.g. `php artisan test yesterday`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. [kopi.io](http://kopy.io/xZREr) i have notice in line 23 & 25 `$this->argument` i was wondering what significant does that have? because i am doing mind liek this [kopi link 2](http://kopy.io/jZ1Tr)

Comment: probably don't use `==` to check for null, use `===` or `is_null()`. Also I think you need to go over the docs here to understand how to use arguments: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan  another thing is to check out some video series on laracasts

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
```

use App\Models\Users;
use DB;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CronJob extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

```
protected $new = 'cronjob';


/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where([
                    ['end_date', '>=',date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+ 1 day'))],//some condition
                    ['start_date', '<=',date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+ 1 day'))],//some condition
                ])->get(); 
    foreach ($users as $values ){

       //Do Something
    }
}
```

}
[Laravel cron](http://interviewhelperphpjs.co)

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:command PushNotification
make changes in app->console->kernal.php write the code below,
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('log:sendPush')->everyMinute();       
    }
crontab -e (in Terminal)
press i to insert in terminal
edit below mentioned line
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/api && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
press escape then write :wq! and press enter
this is the way to edit in terminal
Then write your code in PushNotification created job in public function handle
Enjoy Laravel Cron Job.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).